# Firebase and React - Login with google is not working for Chrome but is working for Microsoft Edge

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firebase-authentication, google-signin

My login function

```
export const socialLogin = selectedProvider => async (
  dispatch,
  getState,
  { getFirebase, getFirestore }
) => {
  const firebase = getFirebase();
  const firestore = getFirestore();
  try {
    let user = await firebase.login({
      provider: selectedProvider,
      type: "popup"
    });
    history.push("/app/home");
    if (user.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
      await firestore.set(`users/${user.user.uid}`, {
        displayName: user.profile.displayName,
        photoURL: user.profile.avatarUrl,
        createdAt: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

the Error that I am getting when I try to log in with google is the following:

```
L {code: "auth/network-request-failed", message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."}
code: "auth/network-request-failed"
message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."
__proto__: Error
```

And I do not understand why because when I try it from Microsoft edge is working.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved when I disabled Ad Blocker